# ¿Cómo realizar esta consulta SQL con LINQ en C#?

Tags: linq

tengo una consulta SQL que funciona y es la siguiente:

```
SELECT campo1, campo2, SUM(valor1) - SUM(valor2) AS Resultado FROM mitabla GROUP BY campo1
```

¿Cómo podría hacer esto mismo pero con LINQ? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La consulta SQL tiene un pequeño error, si en el select incluye campo1 y campo2 sin ninguna función de agregación ocurriría el siguiente error en sql:

> Column 'mitabla .campo2' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Corrigiendo este detalle el equivalente de dicha consulta sería:

```
from t in mitabla group t by new { t.campo1 t.campo2 } into g
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          g.Key.campo1,
                                          g.Key.campo2,
                                          Resultado = g.Sum(x => x.valor1 - x.valor2)
                                      }
```